# Java Date Format parse function failing when submitting a form to a controller in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, date, parsing, internet-explorer, model-view-controller

I am running into an issue with Date parsing in IE 11.  It seems to be occurring in Edge as well.  Please have a look at the following Java code.  This below code is part of a controller method that a form is submitted to.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
stream.setAutoExpireDate(dateFormat.parse(request.getParameter("autoExpireDate")));
```

The output of request.getParameter("autoExpireDate") is "05/30/2018".

When parse is called on that specific date format, passing that string, it hits the following DateFormat.java function:

```
public Date parse(String source) throws ParseException
{
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
    Date result = parse(source, pos);
    if (pos.index == 0)
        throw new ParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + source + "\"" ,
            pos.errorIndex);
    return result;
}
```

For some reason, and only in IE/Edge, I keep getting the following error:

```
Unparseable date: "‎05‎/‎30‎/‎2018"
```

I am very confused as to why this is an "unparseable" date.  The same date string seems to work fine with Chrome and Firefox when I submit the form through the application.

Obviously, pos.index == 0  in the parse function is equaling 0 when the value is passed, but for what reason?  Why would IE/Edge be behaving in such a manner?

I apologize if anything is unclear.  Feel free to ask any questions and I will further clarify.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,

MotoDave452

UPDATE:  While request.getParameter("autoExpireDate") is a string that equals "‎05‎/‎30‎/‎2018", check out the differences in the actual value when using IE compared to Chrome.

IE:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

Comment: I'm sure you know that java code should not depend on browser type. :) Check deeply what is actually inside of the string (source) in case bad and good cases. They must be different. Check getChars() if they look similar.

Comment: I am certainly aware, but thank you for clarifying:)  I am thinking it must be how IE is handling the request parameter value for "autoExpireDate" when it is being passed to the server side controller method.  Please see my response to the answer below for more information on this.

Comment: You can also see the update I posted to my original question above.  Thank you for your insight @Evgeny Zhuravlev it was helpful in solving my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in IE 11 Date Parser, doesn't like unicode characters, it mean, you have to replace them, with something like this

```
Date dateStr = new Date().toLocaleString().replace(/[^A-Za-z 0-9 \.,\?""!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-_=\+;:<>\/\\\|\}\{\[\]`~]*/g, '');
Date date = new Date(dateStr);
```

to avoid the non-asci characters

Comment: Is this why I see autoExpireDate being passed as the following in my request headers in IE:  autoExpireDate=%E2%80%8E05%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E30%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E2018?  But in Chrome it looks as follows:  autoExpireDate=05%2F30%2F2018?

Comment: yes I think so, for more info check this [post](https://www.csgpro.com/blog/2016/08/a-bad-date-with-internet-explorer-11-trouble-with-new-unicode-characters-in-javascript-date-strings)! :D

Comment: I think you are definitely on to something here.  I will do some playing around with the information you have provided to see if this will work for me.  It is much appreciated:)

Comment: I saw your update, now the error can be seen very clearly.

Answer (score 2):

It appears IE is adding non-printable characters to your date.  Try the following:

```
dateStr = source.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");
```